# C++ using declaration, typedef and array type

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++ libstdc++ source code for array, it uses typedef to define an array type,

```
  template<typename _Tp, std::size_t _Nm>
    struct __array_traits
    {
      typedef _Tp _Type[_Nm];
      ...
    };
```

How you use the newer 'using' declaration to relpace the typedef?

Comment: `using _Type = _Tp [_Nm];`

Answer (score 2):

When you `typedef` an array, the aliased-name should be put where a variable name is put if a variable of that type were to be declared.

For example, to `typedef` an `int` array of 10 elements, we should do this:

```
typedef int IntArr[10]; //without typedef, IntArr is just an array of 10 ints
```

Then the `using` declaration will be:

```
using IntArr = int[10];
```

So, in your case, the `using` declaration will be:

```
using _Type = _Tp[_Nm];
```